# Why does my fixed hologram not scale with head movement?

Tags: directx, c++-cx, hololens

I am placing a Direct X sphere using a fixed frame of reference. When I move my head, the sphere hologram stays in place. But it does not scale. It DOES scale when I first place it using PositionHologramAtGaze() (based on example code).

Do I have to handle the scaling when in C++ / Direct X?

// The code below is based on or identical to example code...

```
SpatialPointerPose^ pointerPoseStationary = 
SpatialPointerPose::TryGetAtTimestamp(m_stationaryReferenceFrame- 
>CoordinateSystem, prediction->Timestamp);

m_Sphere->PositionHologramAtGaze(pointerPoseStationary, 2.5f);
```

The sphere draws fine, and stays at a fixed world position, but doesn't scale as I move my head / hololens further away.

For instance in this image we have a person looking at a holographic sphere[Person wearing a hololens looking at holographic sphere](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5d7yD.png)

And what they see is
[Holographic Sphere as seen by wearer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjnR1.png)

Now the user wearing the hololens hardware steps a few meters backwards:

[Person takes a few steps back](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rWdyd.png)

And what they should see is a smaller sphere:
[Smaller sphere](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iY6or.png)

I also observe this in Microsoft's example here:

https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BasicHologram

The cube spins but does not change size as I move backwards.

Comment: Can you maybe add some crudely drawn images of what's happening and what you want to happen? Because I am having a hard time visualizing the problem.

Comment: I added picture links above. My basic question is, I would "think" that Microsoft would supply something to scale the holograph, but perhaps not for Direct X low level. If not, what is the best approach for scaling the object ourselves?

Comment: Are you sure you're not just misunderstanding the example? If it stays in place and you don't see it getting smaller when you walk away, that would mean it has to get bigger. It would be more effort to make the sample do that than to just have it react normally. Aren't you just expecting more difference than you are seeing?

Comment: If I place a sphere at 5 meters away, and place the same sphere at 4 meters away, it has a different size when viewed through the hololens. However, if I place a sphere at 4 meters away, and back up ( approximately) 1 meter, it stays the same size.

Comment: It could be an automatic scaling thing, this is used mostely for UI. Are there any features enabled on the cube? Anything that mentions scaling?

Comment: In the sample hologram positions without distance-related scaling and camera-related rotation. The hologram in the sample is locked to the world by position only. You should modify `SpinningCubeRenderer.Update()` in order to get calculation of it.

Answer (score 1):

I found my own answer.

The HolographicFaceTracking Example uses the coordinate system relative to the glasses.
Line 281
    SpatialCoordinateSystem^ currentCoordinateSystem = m_referenceFrame-

> GetStationaryCoordinateSystemAtTimestamp(prediction->Timestamp);

I misunderstood this method as getting the "Stationary", i.e. "World" coordinate system. But "Stationary" doesn't have this meaning in this context.

It doesn't quite explain why the cube wouldn't change size, or have a reverse scaling, but, once I switched to using this code from the BasicHologram example:

```
// The simplest way to render world-locked holograms is to create a 
stationary reference frame
// based on a SpatialLocator. This is roughly analogous to creating a "world" 
coordinate system
// with the origin placed at the device's position as the app is launched.
m_stationaryReferenceFrame = m_spatialLocator- 
>CreateStationaryFrameOfReferenceAtCurrentLocation();
```

and then

```
pose = SpatialPointerPose::TryGetAtTimestamp(m_stationaryReferenceFrame- 
>CoordinateSystem, prediction->Timestamp);
```

switching to using the CreateStationaryFrameOfReferenceAtCurrentLocation()

gives me the "world locked" coordinate frame.

I think, in my defense, ;>) , the over-loading of the word "stationary" all over the place is a bit confusing, and one needs to be careful. I'm changing my own code to make sure to use "world" and "headset" to refer to the coordinate frames to help eliminate confusion...

Hopefully my answer here will help someone else....